# Handling element collisions on importing/including XML schemas

Tags: xml, xsd

Given schema definitions that define the same element differently, can one import/include both definitions and reference them independently from within a third schema definition?

For example, given:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:example:namespace">
    <element name="message" type="boolean"/>
</schema>
```

and:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:example:namespace">
    <element name="message" type="date"/>
</schema>
```

Can one construct the following:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:example:namespace">
    <complexType name="booleanMessageType">
        <sequence>
            <!-- reference to first definition here -->
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="dateMessageType">
        <sequence>
            <!-- reference to second definition here -->
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot have a schema set that would contain two definitions for the same global element.

If the tag name is important, then instead you could define two types, e.g. messageBoolean and messageDate, then use local element definitions, with the same tag name (**message**) and different types.